# Swift Playground Xcode 6 addAttribute error

Tags: xcode, swift

Im newby in Xcode

These lines worked perfect in playground:

```
meinTfStr = "Hallo ihr lieben Stackoverflower könnt ihr helfen bitte"

var range1 = NSMakeRange(0, 6)
var range2 = NSMakeRange(6, 3)
var range3 = NSMakeRange(9,toend)

var plusStr = NSMutableAttributedString(string: meinTfStr)

plusStr.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.brownColor(), range: NSMakeRange(0, start))
plusStr.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.redColor(), range: NSMakeRange(start, len))
plusStr.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.brownColor(), range: NSMakeRange((start+len),ende))
tf.attributedText = plusStr
```

After copying in Xcode Project I get an error. I marked the lines with `//` and figured out that the error appears in the `plusStr.addAttribute...` line.

```
error: Undefined symbols for architecture i386: TFSs26_forceBridgeFromObjectiveCU__FTPSs9AnyObject_MQ__Q_", referenced from:
linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I dont understand why it worked in playground?

Thanks for all answers!

Comment: Should you not be using the values range1, range2, and range3 somewhere? And where are start, len and end coming from?

Comment: Thanks for giving me an advice. The ranges and variables are defined in the code before. in my opinion the problem caused by the update between beta and xcode6. i put the same code in a new project and it works fine. but i lost one stupid day of my life to figure this out.

Comment: ... and there coming more days like this i think!